# How do you test the linearity assumption without estimated factor values in SEM models?

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

Let's say we would work with this simplified path model.

```
lavaan -> '
  # measurement model
  A =~ ItemA + ItemB + ItemC
  B =~ ItemD + ItemE + ItemF
  C =~ ItemG + ItemH + ItemI

  # path model
  A ~ B + C'
```

How would I then test that B and C do not have a quadratic relationship with A.

Would the following be correct? I square the items of B and C and store them under new variable names ("sqr") in my dataset. And include them in my model as follows.

```
lavaan ->'
  # measurement model
  A =~ ItemA + ItemB + ItemC
  B =~ ItemD + ItemE + ItemF
  C =~ ItemG + ItemH + ItemI

  B_sqr =~ ItemD_sqr + ItemE_sqr + ItemF_sqr
  C_sqr =~ ItemG_sqr + ItemH_sqr + ItemI_sqr

  # path model
  A ~ B + B_sqr + C + C_sqr'
```

Then I look to see if R-squared gets higher by adding the quadratic terms and see if the quadratic parameters become significant.

Or would the following option also work:

```
lavaan ->'
  # measurement model
  A =~ ItemA + ItemB + ItemC
  B =~ ItemD + ItemE + ItemF
  C =~ ItemG + ItemH + ItemI

  # path model
  A ~ B + I(B^2) + C + I(C^2)'
```

Or is the I operator only applicable in lm objects?

What do you think about all this?

Comment: Or would the following option also work: 

lavaan ->
" # Measurement model
  A =~ ItemA + ItemB + ItemC
  B =~ ItemD + ItemE + ItemF
  C =~ ItemG + ItemH + ItemI

# Path model
A ~ B + I(B^2) + C + I(C^2)

Or is the I operator only applicable in lm objects?

Comment: The `I()` operator only works in `formula` objects, and operates on observed variables.  You could use the product-indicator method for estimating latent interaction effects (a quadratic effect is a variable moderating its own effect, so mean-center your indicators and square them to create indicators of a quadratic factor).  The `semTools::indProd()` function is helpful for this, and you can read the references on its help page.

Comment: Ah okay, so the following would be correct to get the indicators:

dat <- indProd(df[ , -1], var1 = 14:18, var2 = 14:18).

And I then put these indicators in here in my measurement model.  

lavaan ->'
  # Measurement model
  A =~ ItemA + ItemB + ItemC
  B =~ ItemD + ItemE + ItemF
  C =~ ItemG + ItemH + ItemI

  B_sqr =~ mc_ItemD_sqr + mc_ItemE_sqr + mc_ItemF_sqr
  C_sqr =~ mc_ItemG_sqr + mc_ItemH_sqr + mc_ItemI_sqr

  # path model
  A ~ B + B_sqr + C + C_sqr'


(*mc = mean-centred)

Comment: Dependent variable ~ latent variable + latent variable_sqr + manifest variable A + manifest variable B ....

1. If I have found out that the square latent variable has a significant effect on the dependent variable, but the linear latent variable does not. Do I then simply throw out the linear latent variable and replace it with the square latent variable or do I keep both in the path model?

2. Can I parcel a square latent variable in the same way as a linear one or does it lose its quadratic effect?

Comment: Syntax looks fine, but you should keep your lower-order terms even if not significant, to ensure the quadratic effect is unbiased.  The linear slope is the (simple) slope of the tangent line touching the curve when that predictor = 0.  Forcing it to be 0 just makes your curve bend suboptimally.  Of course, a quadratic effect is just a simple tool to explore the possibility of nonlinearity; it is not necessarily the "correct" functional form of the predictor's effect.

Comment: ah okay! My model described here is only a simplification of my actual model. The latent variable with conventional, non-squared items is divided into parcels. Should I also parcel out the counterpart, i.e. the latent variable based on quadratic items (or choose the raw items) before I include it in the path model, or would that have an effect on the quadratic effect? Actually, it should have no effect on it.

Comment: If you are parceling, I would just make one parcel to simplify everything.

Comment: So then as follows: 
mod_parcel <- '
    # Measurement models
    A =~ par1 + par2 + par3 + par4
    A_sqr =~ par5
    B =~ par6 + par7 + par8
    C =~ Item1 + Item2 + Item3 + Item4 + Item5
    
    # Path model
    C ~ A + A_sqr + B

Comment: By "one parcel", I mean just calculate a scale mean for each construct.  Then there is no parcel allocation variability.